# Querying MongoDB (Using Edge Collection - The most efficient way?)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've written Users, Clubs and Followers collections for the sake of an example the below. 
I want to find all user documents from the Users collection that are following "A famous club". **How can I find those? and Which way is the fastest?**

More info about '[what do I want to do](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/socialite-open-source-status-feed-part-2-managing-social-graph) - [Edge collections](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/socialitept2-140724104718-phpapp01/95/socialite-the-open-source-status-feed-part-2-managing-the-social-graph-18-638.jpg?cb=1406222239)'

Users collection

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "fullname": "Jared",
    "country": "USA"
}
```

Clubs collection

```
{
    "_id": "12",
    "name": "A famous club"
}
```

Followers collection

```
{
    "_id": "159",
    "user_id": "1",
    "club_id": "12"
}
```

PS: I can get the documents using Mongoose like the below way. However, creating `followers` array takes about 8 seconds with 150.000 records. And second `find` query -which is queried using followers array- takes **about 40 seconds**. Is it normal?

```
Clubs.find(
    { club_id: "12" },  
    '-_id user_id',      // select only one field to better perf.
    function(err, docs){ 

        var followers = [];
        docs.forEach(function(item){
            followers.push(item.user_id)
        })                

        Users.find(
            { _id:{ $in: followers } },
            function(error, users) {
                console.log(users) // RESULTS
        })
})
```

Comment: I don't see the question... You're asking "how can I find it", but you provide the solution yourself. What's your aim? Why would you even *need* all the data of all the followers of a specific club? It probably doesn't make sense to display those results?! Without more context, there's not much to add to your question...

Comment: Hello @mnemosyn, you're right. I've edited the question. I need the most efficient way. In case working on millions record. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Why would you need all that data in RAM at a single time? Anyhow, you'll have to pinpoint where the delay comes from. Keep in mind that the default batch size is only 1,000, so this code will require at least 450 database round trips, plus the actual data transmission. I have no idea what the overhead of mongoose is, but profiling it might help. Also, `$in` on arrays larger than roughly 10,000 elements can be slow. If you need almost all data anyway, might it be faster to load ALL data into RAM first? Or is the entire data set much larger?

Comment: Actually my collections have more fields and I should query two collections to get filtered users count as a result. For instance I want to find records that have DateOfMonth field equal to 'April' from `users` collection as a result set. Then I should find all 'A famous club' followers from my result set. Then I'll be have count of users those DateOfMonth equal to 'April' and follow 'A famous club'.  I've been dealing with MongoDB just a few months. So probably I've done something wrong :)  In fact there are no big data set yet. Almost all works have finished regarding MongoDB but this issue.

Comment: I think I'll give up Edge Collection achitecht. I could get count at the moment when I've added `follower` collection as an embedded document to `users` collection.

{
    "_id": "1",
    "fullname": "Jared",
    "country": "USA",
    "followedClubs": [ { "_id": "12", "name": "A famous club" } ]
}

However I know this is not a best practice.
http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays

Comment: Well, it will make updates slower and can become a problem if the number of `followedClubs` grows large. Essentially, what you want to do is perform a join - your query example is 'truly relational'. If you can somehow store an aggregate of the information you're trying to query upfront, i.e, be more write-heavy, that would be better. Anyway, I still don't see why all that information is required - do you really need all the users, or just the count?

Comment: @mnemosyn, suppose that you're a manager of 'a famous club'. You want to see how many people follow your club and what percent of them between 18 and 25 years of age. So, I need to query `Followers` collection to know how many people follow the club and secondly I need to query `Users` using first result set to know how many `Users` between 18 and 25 years of age :)

Comment: By the way, I've tested queries using 150.000 records. 
- I queried `Users` collection using embedded documents ( I had added 108 fictive 

subdocuments as `followedClubs` to each User document and I added an index to subdocuments ) 

in 37 seconds.  
- I queried `Users` and `Followers` collections separately they took 82 seconds.  
- I queried `Users` collection - using *only one* embedded document - it took just 1 second. 
- I queried `Followers` collection to find follower users it took less than 1 second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70626/discussion-between-mnemosyn-and-user3765109).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no an eligible formula to manipulate join many-to-many relation on MongoDB. So I combined collections as embedded documents like the below. But the most important taks in this case *creating indexes*. For instance if you want to query by `followingClubs` you should create an index like `schema.index({ 'followingClubs._id':1 })` using Mongoose. And if you want to query `country` and `followingClubs` you should create another index like `schema.index({ 'country':1, 'followingClubs._id':1 })`

Pay attention when working with Embedded Documents: http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays

Then you can get your documents fastly. I've tried to get count of 150.000 records using this way it took only 1 second. It's enough for me...

ps: we *musn't forget* that in my tests my `Users` collection has never experienced any data fragmentation. Therefore my queries may demonstrated good performance. Especially, `followingClubs` array of embedded documents.

Users collection

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "fullname": "Jared",
    "country": "USA",
    "followingClubs": [ {"_id": "12"} ]
}
```

Clubs collection

```
{
    "_id": "12",
    "name": "A famous club"
}
```